# pattern recognition while taking pictures and identify the patterns and do manipulation on image accordingly

Tags: objective-c, ios5, image-processing, design-patterns, image-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recognize some patterns in image ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913911/recognize-some-patterns-in-image-ios)

My question is that I am creating an application in which the pages are to be scanned.
The pages are pure white and there are black patterns on the all four corners of the paper.
I want to recognize the black patterns on the paper and the image should adjust like all anything beyond that patterns should cut off.
Please provide me some suggestions on how to achieve this approach. I read on the net and find opencv but I do not get anything on this.

The below is the image which defines the patterns:-
[image]

The image consist of pure white background and four black patterns in the corner.I need to recognize these black patterns in the all four corners all then process the image.One corner shown in oval to highlight it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Maurits please see the image shown in the question.