# Match some predefined pattern ispresent in the image captured from camera or not and if then found their coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recognize Black patterns appearing on the four corners of the image ios using opencv or some other technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913911/recognize-black-patterns-appearing-on-the-four-corners-of-the-image-ios-using-op)

I want to create a app like shotnote app(basically its camera feature).
It is a page scanning app that is used to scan special type of paper.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shot-note/id411332997?mt=8

Refer first two screenshots

You can check the functionality what I am searching in the following video:-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F_1iu4pDkQ

In my app

The paper background will be white and the pattern will be in black.

What I want is when I take a image from camera then it should match with the pattern (image or mages) and if patterns are present in that captured image then image should be cropped like in the way so that the patterns should appear at the corners of the image.

Basically I need to detect that the patterns are present and after that I want their coordinates so that I can crop the image accordingly.

Patterns you can assume as rectangle or L shape .

I am surfing for this from the last two weeks and still struggling with it.

Please provide me some sample code or some suggestions which I should follow.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked this same question a few times now. You already have a bounty on the original question, so I'd just wait a bit and see what kind of answers you get for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the pattern is always undistorted (i.e. no or very littly perspective in the original image) template matching, e.g. with a normalised cross correlation will do the trick just fine.

Comment: can you please post some code regarding this.It would be a great help to me.